# Android drawBitmap error

Tags: android

I'm using drawBitmap to draw sprites, it works fine on my phone but not on my tablet.

The sprite is a 32x32 grid

Mobile ( Android 2.3.6)

http://sfidasoft.com/agustin/view_1.jpg

[view_1.jpg]

Tablet ( Android 4.1.2)

http://sfidasoft.com/agustin/view_2.jpg
[view_2.jpg]

Code

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, new Rect(0,0,32,32), new Rect(0,0,32,32), null);
```

please help!

LOGCAT

02-27 14:05:12.203: D/AndroidRuntime(1226): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
02-27 14:05:12.203: D/AndroidRuntime(1226): CheckJNI is ON
02-27 14:05:12.530: D/AndroidRuntime(1226): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
02-27 14:05:12.662: D/dalvikvm(1171): GC_EXPLICIT freed 40K, 52% free 2660K/5511K, external 716K/1038K, paused 92ms
02-27 14:05:12.662: W/ActivityManager(849): No content provider found for: 
02-27 14:05:13.188: W/ActivityManager(849): No content provider found for: 
02-27 14:05:13.223: D/PackageParser(849): Scanning package: /data/app/vmdl394565078.tmp
02-27 14:05:14.703: I/PackageManager(849): Removing non-system package:com.example.latorre
02-27 14:05:14.703: I/ActivityManager(849): Force stopping package com.example.latorre uid=10007
02-27 14:05:14.703: I/Process(849): Sending signal. PID: 1206 SIG: 9
02-27 14:05:14.733: I/WindowManager(849): WIN DEATH: Window{b6643760 SurfaceView paused=false}
02-27 14:05:14.733: E/InputDispatcher(849): channel 'b666b000 com.example.latorre/com.example.latorre.Main (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
02-27 14:05:14.748: E/InputDispatcher(849): channel 'b666b000 com.example.latorre/com.example.latorre.Main (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
02-27 14:05:14.783: I/WindowManager(849): WIN DEATH: Window{b666b000 com.example.latorre/com.example.latorre.Main paused=false}
02-27 14:05:14.874: W/InputManagerService(849): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 1206 uid 10007
02-27 14:05:15.721: D/PackageManager(849): Scanning package com.example.latorre
02-27 14:05:15.721: I/PackageManager(849): Package com.example.latorre codePath changed from /data/app/com.example.latorre-1.apk to /data/app/com.example.latorre-2.apk; Retaining data and using new
02-27 14:05:15.722: I/PackageManager(849): Unpacking native libraries for /data/app/com.example.latorre-2.apk
02-27 14:05:15.732: D/installd(793): DexInv: --- BEGIN '/data/app/com.example.latorre-2.apk' ---
02-27 14:05:15.867: D/dalvikvm(944): GC_EXPLICIT freed 181K, 49% free 3065K/5895K, external 2094K/2598K, paused 41ms
02-27 14:05:16.353: D/dalvikvm(1235): DexOpt: couldn't find field Landroid/graphics/BitmapFactory$Options;.inMutable
02-27 14:05:16.623: D/dalvikvm(1235): DexOpt: load 99ms, verify+opt 332ms
02-27 14:05:16.715: D/installd(793): DexInv: --- END '/data/app/com.example.latorre-2.apk' (success) ---
02-27 14:05:16.715: W/PackageManager(849): Code path for pkg : com.example.latorre changing from /data/app/com.example.latorre-1.apk to /data/app/com.example.latorre-2.apk
02-27 14:05:16.715: W/PackageManager(849): Resource path for pkg : com.example.latorre changing from /data/app/com.example.latorre-1.apk to /data/app/com.example.latorre-2.apk
02-27 14:05:16.715: D/PackageManager(849):   Activities: com.example.latorre.Main
02-27 14:05:16.723: I/ActivityManager(849): Force stopping package com.example.latorre uid=10007
02-27 14:05:17.082: I/installd(793): move /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.example.latorre-2.apk@classes.dex -> /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.example.latorre-2.apk@classes.dex
02-27 14:05:17.082: D/PackageManager(849): New package installed in /data/app/com.example.latorre-2.apk
02-27 14:05:17.132: I/ActivityManager(849): Force stopping package com.example.latorre uid=10007
02-27 14:05:17.229: D/dalvikvm(849): GC_EXPLICIT freed 992K, 45% free 4410K/7943K, external 5272K/6583K, paused 45ms
02-27 14:05:17.262: D/dalvikvm(977): GC_EXPLICIT freed 79K, 51% free 2869K/5767K, external 716K/1038K, paused 76ms
02-27 14:05:17.362: D/dalvikvm(849): GC_EXPLICIT freed 8K, 45% free 4404K/7943K, external 5039K/6293K, paused 87ms
02-27 14:05:17.407: W/ResourceType(849): Failure getting entry for 0x7f060000 (t=5 e=0) in package 0 (error -75)
02-27 14:05:17.432: I/installd(793): unlink /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.example.latorre-1.apk@classes.dex
02-27 14:05:17.432: D/AndroidRuntime(1226): Shutting down VM
02-27 14:05:17.442: D/dalvikvm(1226): GC_CONCURRENT freed 99K, 72% free 291K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 0ms+0ms
02-27 14:05:17.442: D/jdwp(1226): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
02-27 14:05:17.442: D/dalvikvm(1226): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
02-27 14:05:17.602: D/VoiceDialerReceiver(1096): onReceive Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED dat=package:com.example.latorre flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.voicedialer/.VoiceDialerReceiver (has extras) }
02-27 14:05:17.602: V/RecognizerEngine(1096): deleteCachedGrammarFiles /data/data/com.android.voicedialer/files/openentries.txt
02-27 14:05:17.602: D/VoiceDialerReceiver(1096): onReceive Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.example.latorre flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.voicedialer/.VoiceDialerReceiver (has extras) }
02-27 14:05:17.602: V/RecognizerEngine(1096): deleteCachedGrammarFiles /data/data/com.android.voicedialer/files/openentries.txt
02-27 14:05:17.663: D/AndroidRuntime(1242): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
02-27 14:05:17.677: D/AndroidRuntime(1242): CheckJNI is ON
02-27 14:05:17.813: W/RecognitionManagerService(849): no available voice recognition services found
02-27 14:05:18.075: D/AndroidRuntime(1242): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
02-27 14:05:18.095: I/ActivityManager(849): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.example.latorre/.Main } from pid 1242
02-27 14:05:18.123: D/AndroidRuntime(1242): Shutting down VM
02-27 14:05:18.143: D/dalvikvm(1242): GC_CONCURRENT freed 100K, 70% free 315K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 0ms+1ms
02-27 14:05:18.143: D/dalvikvm(1242): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
02-27 14:05:18.272: I/ActivityManager(849): Start proc com.example.latorre for activity com.example.latorre/.Main: pid=1250 uid=10007 gids={}
02-27 14:05:18.552: D/CREADO(1250): 1
02-27 14:05:18.973: D/gralloc_goldfish(1250): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
02-27 14:05:19.073: I/ActivityManager(849): Displayed com.example.latorre/.Main: +957ms
02-27 14:05:19.113: D/dalvikvm(1250): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 43K, 51% free 2671K/5379K, external 972K/1038K, paused 69ms
02-27 14:05:24.303: D/dalvikvm(944): GC_EXPLICIT freed 64K, 48% free 3078K/5895K, external 2102K/2598K, paused 44ms
02-27 14:05:29.303: D/dalvikvm(1020): GC_EXPLICIT freed 92K, 52% free 2697K/5511K, external 716K/1038K, paused 11ms
02-27 14:05:34.327: D/dalvikvm(1096): GC_EXPLICIT freed 333K, 52% free 2662K/5511K, external 716K/1038K, paused 26ms
02-27 14:05:39.323: D/dalvikvm(1171): GC_EXPLICIT freed 7K, 52% free 2658K/5511K, external 716K/1038K, paused 12ms

Comment: Where's the question? I only see colored squares in your links

Comment: Does it throw an error? Please post the logcat output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
final int color = 0xff424242;    // put your color
final Paint paint = new Paint();
final Rect rect = new Rect(0,0,32,32);


paint.setAntiAlias(true);
canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
paint.setColor(color);
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);
```

Try to put convertPixelsToDp(32, context) instead of 32

```
/**
 * This method converts dp unit to equivalent pixels, depending on device density. 
 * 
 * @param dp A value in dp (density independent pixels) unit. Which we need to convert into pixels
 * @param context Context to get resources and device specific display metrics
 * @return A float value to represent px equivalent to dp depending on device density
 */
public static float convertDpToPixel(float dp, Context context){
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
    float px = dp * (metrics.densityDpi / 160f);
    return px;
}

/**
 * This method converts device specific pixels to density independent pixels.
 * 
 * @param px A value in px (pixels) unit. Which we need to convert into db
 * @param context Context to get resources and device specific display metrics
 * @return A float value to represent dp equivalent to px value
 */
public static float convertPixelsToDp(float px, Context context){
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
    float dp = px / (metrics.densityDpi / 160f);
    return dp;
}
```

Comment: Still not working. 
Can it be a problem with the dpi?